# Do Visual Studio database references follow the transitive property differently from DLL references?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, database-project

I've noticed that if I write have three libraries in .NET with the following dependency chain: A-->B-->C
I can have a reference in A to B and a reference in B to C, without an *explicit* reference from A to C (of course, the A-->C dependency is *implied*).

If I try this with database projects however, the build breaks until I add the reference *explicitly* in A to C.

Is this a difference between the two types of reference? Or is there some other factor that's causing it, which I'm misattributing to the difference between the project types?
If it's the former, then why are they different?

It's not the end of the world to add a few of these references by hand, of course, I'm mostly just curious.

Comment: I imagine the database projects need explicit references because the resulting database deployments need explicit references.  It's fundamentally not the same thing as a code reference between DLLs.  With DLLs as long as the library can be loaded somehow at runtime then the code would work.  (Side note: What does any of this have to do with the tags on the question?)

Comment: It is pretty normal, public types from C leak into the metadata of B.  Small changes in A can make the C# compiler insist that it needs to know more about C types so it can reliably select method overloads.

Comment: What does this have to do with asynchronous and async-await?

Comment: The tags were completely wrong. I must have just banged the keyboard and not noticed. Sorry.